# How to add and compare keys of a generic hash table in Java?

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, hash, hashtable

I'm writing my own class for a generic hash table and trying to create an adding method as well as a method for comparing keys and returning true or false if they exist. So far my add method is not adding anything into my buckets, and my in my main, I cant pass any data type into my generic compare method without it asking me to define a new method with that type. Could anyone help point out the issues with my code as I'm trying to learn how to implement the data structure? Thank you.

My node and my table classes

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Objects;

class GenericHashNode <K, V> {
    
    K key;
    V value;
    
    GenericHashNode<K, V> next;
    
    public GenericHashNode (K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        next = null;
    }
    
    public GenericHashNode() {
        next = null;
    }
    
}



public class GenericHashTable <K, V> {

    private ArrayList<GenericHashNode<K, V> > hashArray;
    private int tableSize;

    
    public GenericHashTable(int tableSize)
    {
        hashArray = new ArrayList<>(tableSize);
        this.tableSize = tableSize;
 
        for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
            hashArray.add(new GenericHashNode());
        }          
    }
    
    private int getTableSize() {
        return tableSize;
    }
    
    private int createHashCode(K key)
    {
        int h = key.hashCode();
        h = h % getTableSize();
        int hashCode = h < 0 ? h -= -h : h;
        
        return hashCode;
    }
    
    public void add(K key) {
        
        int hashIndex = createHashCode(key);
        
        GenericHashNode head = hashArray.get(hashIndex);
        GenericHashNode newNode = new GenericHashNode(key, key);
        
        newNode.next = head.next;
        head.next = newNode;
        
    }
    
    public boolean compare(K key) {
        
        int hashIndex = createHashCode(key);
        GenericHashNode current = new GenericHashNode();
        current = hashArray.get(0);
        
        Iterator<GenericHashNode<K, V>> iterate = hashArray.iterator(); 
        
        while(iterate.hasNext()) {
            if(current == null) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            else {
                if(current.key == key) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    current = current.next;
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        return false;
        
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: What's this `int hashCode = h < 0 ? h -= -h : h;`? That `-=` in the middle does not look right.

Comment: `if(current.key == key)` should use equals since `key` is not a primitive

Comment: Also it doesn't look like you're looping through your linked nodes in `compare`. Getting an iterator for your buckets makes no sense since you should *know* which bucket to look in. You need to keep looping to `.next` until `.next` is null.

Comment: @f1sh Just with building the methods correctly, my add isn't adding anything and my compare doesn't accept data types

Comment: @AliasCartellano in debug mode checking the buckets of the array

Comment: @AliasCartellano Its already doing that im pretty sure

Comment: @asdsad when I [checked your code](https://www.online-java.com/vsX1RLxjHg) the add function is adding appropriately(The values are there) and your compare method is running(you suggest it should accept datatypes, I request you elaborate because it accepts the exact datatypes you set for a new GenericHashtable), so I think your issues(besides the fixes suggested by other commentors) lie in the main method you have not shown.